# TSQL search for multiple conditions

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I've learned that I can search multiple fields using something like:

```
DECLARE @srch nvarchar(40) 
    SET @srch = '%something%'

SELECT * FROM DataTable dt
    WHERE CONCAT(dt.field1, dt.field2) LIKE @srch
```

But is there a way to search for multiple criteria other than with multiple ORs?

```
DECLARE @srch1 nvarchar(40), @srch2 nvarchar(40), @srch3 nvarchar(40),  
    SET @srch1 = '%this%'
    SET @srch2 = '%that%'
    SET @srch3 = '%the other%'

SELECT * FROM DataTable dt
    WHERE  CONCAT(dt.field1, dt.field2) LIKE @srch1 
        OR CONCAT(dt.field1, dt.field2) LIKE @srch2 
        OR CONCAT(dt.field1, dt.field2) LIKE @srch3
```

Thank you!

Comment: @t-clausen.dk - `CONCAT` was introduced in SQL Server 2012

Comment: FTS is one option http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571.aspx

Comment: @MartinSmith thx. I guess I am a dinosaur

Comment: @Alex Thanks! I want to work with FTS, but don't have time just now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
DECLARE @srch TABLE (srch_field nvarchar(40))

INSERT INTO @srch VALUES ( '%this%'), ('%that%') ,('%the other%')

SELECT * FROM DataTable dt
WHERE  EXISTS (
  SELECT NULL FROM @srch s WHERE CONCAT(dt.field1, dt.field2) LIKE srch_field
)
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked a treat, though it did seem a bit slow.  Is it, or is it just this computer that I got 2nd hand from Fred Flintstone?